How to find areas/relations inside a country, excluding certain places
Some time ago I asked this question to get an idea of how I could look for gated communities in a given country (e.g. Argentina).
Now I would like to find the same, but excluding certain political divisions. I have the following code thus far, but it isn't working as expected:
{{geocodeArea:Argentina}} -> .searchArea;

(
  {{geocodeArea:Partido del Pilar}};
  {{geocodeArea:Partido de Escobar}};
  {{geocodeArea:Partido de Tigre}};
  {{geocodeArea:Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires}};
)-> .excludedArea;


(
  //Ways marked as private
  way["access"="private"](area.searchArea); 
  >;
  is_in;
  wr(pivot)["landuse"="residential"]["name"][!"residential"][!"gated_community"][!"barrier"][!"admin_level"];
) -> .allAreas;

(
  way["access"="private"](area.excludedArea); 
  >;
  is_in;
  wr(pivot)["landuse"="residential"]["name"][!"residential"][!"gated_community"][!"barrier"][!"admin_level"];
) -> .excludedAreas;

(
  .allAreas;
  -
  .excludedAreas;
) -> .result;

out geom;

I would like to get the results in the same way as they are obtained in the answer that was given my previous question.
